# Rails: update votes_count after user voted on pins

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a pretty simple rails app where users can upvote pins. The system I implemented is working well, But I would like the number of votes updated after each votes through an ajax method.

Here is my upvote system as how it is now:

**in app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:**

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { count: @pin.votes_count } }
 end
end
```

**in my app/views/pins/index.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to upvote_pin_path(pin), method: :post, remote: true do %>

        <% if pin.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).empty? %>

            <span class="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>

        <% else %>

            <span class="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-star" style="color:#c0392b"></i>

        <% end %>

<% end %>
            <span class="votes-count">
              <%= pluralize(pin.votes.count, "") %>
            </span>
```

So everytime someone upvote a pin, the vote is visible only after refreshing the page. Any ideas?

I know I should call the ajax method inside an upvote.js.erb file in my views, but that is where I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to avoid those messy .js.erb files, though you can certainly do it that way. Once you're making a lot of Ajax calls, though, you end up with a whole lot of files. Ryan Bates has a phenomenal screencast on this technique [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised).

To do it without, here's the recipe. You'll need to put a `respond_to` block in your controller action. Right now, now matter how the request comes in, you're redirecting to the pin path, which I'm assuming is the current path in this case, which reloads the page. That's what you're trying to avoid.

Ajax request by default come in to controllers as javascript, or js, request types. You can switch that type if you want (JSON is a popular alternative), but let's keep it simple for now. So configure the `respond_to` block for a js request:

```
# app/controllers/pins_controller.rb
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])

  if @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        flash[:notice] =  "Thanks for your recommendation."
        redirect_to(pin_path)
      }

      format.js {
        @count = @pin.votes.count.to_s
        render nothing: true, count: @count # anything else you put in here will be available in the `success` callback on the JQuery ajax method.
      }
    end
  else 
    format.html {
      flash[:notice] =  "Unable to process your request. Please try again."
      redirect_to(pin_path)
    }

    format.js {
      render nothing: true # anything else you put in here will be available in the `error` callback on the JQuery ajax method.
    }
  end
end
```

Now that the controller has passed back the value, you need to retrieve it in your Ajax request:

```
     $.ajax({
       .....
       success:function(data){
         $('span.votes-count').text(data.count)
       }
```

Two things (at least) won't be available to you as you're using them with this method. The flash message, and the ruby pluralization method. To get around the second one you'll need to use the Ruby pluralization in the controller and return the text you want. To get around the first one, you'll need to set up some javascript that imitates the Rails flash message technique, as well as pass the flash message back to the Ajax call.

Comment: First, thank you for your detailed answer Steel. So I added your code to my controller. Then I added the ajax request in a votes.js file in my javascript files. I am not sure what to put as #my_target_element id. Could you detail a lil bit more that Ajax request I should use? Thanks

Comment: Sure. I changed the success call to align more with your example.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, so I updated with this ajax request, but it still needs the page to be refreshed to show the updated number of upvotes. Damn... Sorry :')

Comment: No it doesn't. I use this technique almost every day. If you're still struggling, I would recommend starting with the Ryan Bates Railscast.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not testing the code I'm giving you. You'll need to adapt the technique to your specific environment.

Comment: Yep, all right, i'll try my best and verify your answer asa its fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You should have your pinvotes inside an span with a class for searching after the ajax is complete

```
$(".fa.fa-star").click(function(){
     var _this=$(this)
     $.ajax({
       .....
        success:function(msg){
            _this.parent().parent().find('.votes-count').html(msg); //Accesing the parent then you should acces a span to your votes
         }
     })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But I cant still figured it out - I am pretty new to rails and even more to ajax fuctions... I added remote: true to my upvote buton, but the votes_count is not updating, that's what I need to update through my ajax method

Comment: i don't know how rails works , could you put the html that the code in app/views/pins/index.html.erb
prints? maybe i could be more help with that

Comment: Ok - so i edited the my question with more codes in my index.html.erb

Comment: 1.- <span class="text-decoration: none;"> <---you cant do that, that is a style not a class
2.- access from your click to the parent of the element and search for .votes-count and modify its .html() with the new votes

Comment: Ok thanks I'm gonna look into this. I'll keep you informed. thanks again for your time and advises

Comment: whenever you want... =) i don't know anything about rails but this problem is about jquery and javascript ;)

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer i think this isnt the right way to go - I can't figure out. Hope someone will jump in to help :)

Comment: It's misleading to say this is just a jquery/js problem. It's both Rails and Javascript.

Comment: why? he know how to iterate and put the right code to do the job. he just needs help to put appropiate html and javascript/Jquery code

Comment: He certainly did not. He didn't have a respond_to block in his controller, and his requests were getting routed to a redirect. @Ernesto, You said you don't know anything about Rails and your answer reflects that, because it missed this critical part of the answer. It's poor form of you to downvote me in retaliation, though. Stick to what you know.